# Повторный вызов Activity с заполнением полей

Tags: android, android-intent

Есть активити 1. По нажатию на кнопку открывается активити 2, в котором в пустые поля вводятся юзером данные, которые считываются и отдаются активити 1 (передаю через интент и в активити 1 сохраняю в List для отображения в RecyclerView). Юзер по нажатию на пункт в RecyclerView, который находится в активити 1, может редактировать данные, то есть по нажатию надо опять открыть активити 2 но уже с заполненными полями. Не пойму как это реализовать.

Comment: Вам нужно сохранять введенное в место, не зависящее от жизненного цикла и вообще состояния активити (в БД, файл, преференсы и тп.) Потом читать оттуда и изменять в нем при редактировании

Comment: @pavlofff предположим, я сохраняю-таки данные из полей в файл. как мне вызвать активити 2 для редактирования данных и поля заполнить уже ранее введенными данными?

Comment: при запуске второго активити отправляйте с ней интент с признаком - вводить новые значения или редактировать ранее введенные (напр. -1 - новые, число - номер записи для редактирования). При старте второй активити по этому признаку определеяете нужно ли предварительно заполнить поля из БД, тогда читаете из БД нужное и вставляете в виджеты.

Comment: @pavlofff не сочтите за труд, как это написать. Интент с признаком.

Comment: Признак это просто какое то число, к примеру, отправляете его как обычные данные через интент. При получении проверяете, чему равно это число, если -1 то выполняете ветку для новых значений, если больше, то считываете из БД данные по полученной позиции и ими заполняете виджеты.

Comment: Ок. Попробую! .